# Query function in google sheets empty output

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the following query function with mixed column data but it returns with "Query completed with an empty output."

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(Consumables!$C:$N),"Select Col4, Col1 Where Col12="&C1&" order by Col1 ",))
```

Although, if I removed the "&C1&" and replaced it with the number I want it works which is what I don't really want to do.

This is a link for the sheet if anyone wants to help
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h5GHlf9Pzw05WGseYdJ5CbDpRfCmlKQRpowFqrliFcY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have transformed data into text, you need to do `Col12='"&C1&"'`

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(Consumables!$C:$N),"Select Col4, Col1 Where Col12='"&C1&"' order by Col1 ",))
```